# Regex to match sub directories but not parent directory

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling a bit to get a regex for PHP to match subdirectories but to avoid the parent directory.

`http://www.address.com/2000/12/31/` -> Don't match

`http://www.address.com/2000/12/31/whatever/` -> Match

This what I tried but seems not to work: `#http://www\.address\.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.`#

Comment: To be clear: you want to match the second but not the first url? And what do you mean by `seems not to work`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot at the end will only match a single character, you want one or more:

```
#http://www\.address\.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.+#
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to the post ;-) A useful link on this one is: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Without anchor at the end, a single dot is OK to match the second example.